# How to create a dynamically allocated memory fault detectable by Valgrind?

Tags: c, security, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to use a real C program for exemplifying memory safety concepts. The idea is to inject or delete some statements in a program that uses `malloc` in order to create a memory problem. The modified version of the program must lend to a memory fault at runtime. The problem should be detectable by [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/), and thus be related to dynamically allocated memory (not stack memory). It should also have a pre-made test case or test input to trigger the problem.

I don't understand how to create a dynamically allocated memory fault.

Can you present an example and explain a modification to a program that causes a memory fault when the program is executed with a given input?

Comment: Rather than ask for code to be given to you instead explain what it is that is preventing you from writing the code yourself. That is, ask a specific question that will help you write the code that you need. For example, is it that you don't know what a memory leak is and how to create one? Is it you don't know how to write to out of bounds memory? etc.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum, I edited the question. How to create a memory fault is actually what I need to learn from this question.

Comment: What does "memory fault" mean to you? There are different types of faults - memory leak, reading uninitialised memory, writing invalid memory, to name a few. And what do you mean by "given input"? Input to what?

Comment: @kaylum: By memory fault, I meant any of the existing ones. By "given input", I meant an input to the program that creates the memory fault at runtime.

Comment: It's really not clear what you need. For example: `char buffer[10]; scanf("%s", buffer);`. That will cause a buffer overflow if the user enters more than 9 characters. Is that what you want?

Comment: @kaylum: Yes, that's what I want. But I would like to have a more interesting example to show. Consider the following requirements for the example: 1) it's a real-world non-dummy program, 2) it's related to memory allocation with `malloc`, 3) it's detectable by Valgrind.

Comment: Well then this is not really a question about something you don't understand but a request to do work for you. Why don't you attempt to do it yourself first? If there is something specific you don't understand then you can come back to ask.

Comment: @kaylum: I've tried, I compiled, executed and modified simple programs in C (e.g, [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)). Then, I've analyzed the outputs of Valgrind for a given input of the program. However, I'm not familiar with C and I don't know a more complex example of an allocated memory fault. Please post an answer if you can give a real-world example of memory allocation fault.

Comment: You can try to allocate very large amount of memory to get allocation failure (if this is what you are trying to achieve). But Valgrind does not intended to detect this kind of failures.

Comment: The Valgrind manual has several examples http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html (though without associated code examples). You should read this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PaulFloyd, your examples and the associated links to the Valgrind documentation make it clear to me how to inject memory faults in existing programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a few examples.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int*pi1  = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    if (pi1[5]) // ERROR here, see 4.2.2 in the manual
        ;
    free(pi1);

    int* pi2 = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    free(pi2);
    if (pi2[5]) // ERROR here, a variation of 4.2.1 in the manual
        ;

    int* pi3 = (int*)0x500000000000U;
    if (*pi3) // ERROR and probably a crash, see 4.2.1 in the manual
       ;
}
```

Clearly these are trivial examples. In more involved real world problems you should be aware that the 'uninitialized' nature of memory is transitive. Valgrind does not emit error messages until the use of the uninitialized memory has an effect on the behaviour of the software.

For example, you could have

1. Structure s1 allocated with malloc.
2. All fields of s1 get initialized except f1.
3. s1 gets copied into s2. No error emitted.
4. s2 gets copied into s3. No error emitted.
5. A read is done on s3.f1. Now Valgrind emits an error. It will give the stack here and the allocation stack of step 1.